# Connecting my Xbox 360 to my Raspberry Pi 2 to use an OpenVPN connection

Tags: linux, iptables, openvpn, xbox360

Here is my brief setup:

- Xbox360
- Raspberry PI 2 running ArchLinuxARM (alarm)
- The raspberry pi's main ethernet port has a cable connecting directly to my main router
- The xbox has a cross-over cable connected to a ethernet-to-usb on the raspberry pi
- I am using the openvpn systemd service (which creates the `tun0` device)

I have purchased a VPN account, and wanted to route my xbox 360 traffic through it.  After [doing](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Internet_sharing) [research](http://www.linuxquestions.org/linux/answers/Networking/Connecting_to_XBox_Live_through_a_linux_computer_connected_to_a_wireless_LAN), I was able to get my xbox using my raspberry pi as a router.  My raspberry pi connects to the network/internet via `eth0`, and has a cross-over cable connected to my xbox via `eth1`.

`eth0` has a static ip to `10.0.0.31`, `eth1` has a static ip of `10.0.1.100`, and the xbox has a static ip of `10.0.1.101`.

Here is my iptables config:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Apr  6 00:37:36 2015
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [91:6512]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [45:4220]
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.101/32 -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3074 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 10.0.1.101/32 -i eth0 -p udp -m multiport --dports 88,3074 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr  6 00:37:36 2015
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Mon Apr  6 00:37:36 2015
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [8:3607]
:INPUT ACCEPT [2:144]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:86]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [2:146]
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3074 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.101
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p udp -m multiport --ports 88,3074 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.0.1.101
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Apr  6 00:37:36 2015
```

My xbox configuration is (using google dns, by the way):

- IP Settings: Manual
- IP Address: `10.0.1.101`
- Subnet Mask: `255.255.255.0`
- Gateway: `10.0.1.100`
- DNS Settings: Manual
- Primary: `8.8.8.8`
- Secondary: `8.8.4.4`

This works perfectly fine when my VPN connection is off.

When I turn my openvpn service on, the xbox will no longer connect to the internet (stating a DNS error), however, the raspberry pi is still able to surf the internet, and I can confirm that I am being successfully routed through my VPN.

When the VPN is off, the xbox connects fine to the internet and works as expected.

I'm not familiar enough with ip tables and this general routing set up to know if logs are being generated, if the issue is my iptables config, the xbox, or something else.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

**Update:**

I have connected another linux laptop (which is using NetworkManager, if that matters) to `eth1`, with the following configuration:

- IPv4 Method: Manual
- DNS Servers: `10.0.0.1`
- IP Address: `10.0.1.101`
- Netmask: `255.255.255.0`
- Gateway: `10.0.1.100`

When the vpn connection is off, I am able to use the internet fine.  When the vpn is turned on, I can access the LAN fine (and can even ssh into the raspberry pi using it's `10.0.0.31` ip address), however, DNS is not working, and I also can't ping external addresses.

Is there any set of logs I should be setting a tail on to see exactly what's happening?

**Update #2:**

I am using [this arch linux package](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/private-internet-access-vpn/) for OpenVPN profiles, and have a file configured for automatic login.  I noticed that it fires a script that modifies resolv.conf in some way, which might be doing something.

Comment: You could try to replace the xbox with another computer. You'll hopefully get the same error but it's probably easier to get debugging info out of a computer than the xbox.

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion, is there any sort of log file I should be watching?

Comment: Do you have to use a raspberry pi? This would be a lot easier if using something like ddwrt on a router. You wouldn't need a crossover cable either.

Comment: If I had a spare router that could run ddwrt, I wouldn't have asked the question to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding [another guide](http://mwmanning.com/2013/02/11/Geospoofing-with-the-Raspberry-Pi.html), modified the iptables a bit for my various services I wanted routed.

The resulting file ended up looking like this:

```
filter

# Allows all loopback (lo0) traffic and drop all traffic to 127/8 that doesn't use lo0
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT ! -i lo -d 127.0.0.0/8 -j REJECT

# Accepts all established inbound connections
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT

# Forward all data related to our requests
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED

# Allows all outbound traffic
# You could modify this to only allow certain traffic
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT

# Allows HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites)
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow Transmission daemon from anywhere, with default ports
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9091 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 51413 -j ACCEPT

# Allows SSH connections (change the port number if you need to)
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

# Allow ping
-A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT

# log iptables denied calls (access via 'dmesg' command)
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 5/min -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables denied: " --log-level 7

# Reject all other inbound - default deny unless explicitly allowed policy:
-A INPUT -j REJECT

COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [1:148]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:148]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
-A POSTROUTING -o tun0 -j MASQUERADE

COMMIT
```

Some of this is just guess work, and I'm sure it can be optimized/improved, but this is working for me for the time being, and is a little more generalized (no specific ips, etc.)

This did modify my set up a little; now I connect my xbox through wifi, and can just manually set my gateway to the raspberry pi's static ip; it works great for the xbox, my laptop, phone, etc.  Just added new network profiles so I can jump on and off the vpn connection without any trouble at all.